# sscanf() with two string parameters

Tags: c++, scanf

I want to create the command `/kick playername reason` in C++, so I tried it:

```
if (IPlayer.IsOnline() && IPlayer.GetAdmin() >= 3
    && sscanf(command, "/kick %[a-z | A-Z | 0-9/<>|.,~*;`:!'^+%&/()=?_-£#${[]}€] %[a-z | A-Z | 0-9/<>|.,~*;`:!'^+%&/()=?_-£#${[]}€]",
        &playername, &reasonkick) == 2)
```

But nothing happens when I use the command in game. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, write a minimal program with just that `sscanf` and some fixed test input to illustrate the problem. You may even find the problem yourself in the process of forming the simplified example.

Comment: I don't think you understand how `%[...]` works in `sscanf()`. Why do you have multiple `|` and space in it?

Comment: If `playername` and `reasontokick` are strings, you shouldn't have `&` before them. Arrays automatically become pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: In C++ you would normally use a `std::stringstream` rather than `sscanf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf()` does not support regular expressions. The way you are using the `%[]` placeholder is indeed wrong syntax. Try this instead:

```cpp
if (IPlayer.IsOnline() &&
    (IPlayer.GetAdmin() >= 3) &&
    (sscanf(command, "/kick %N[^ ] %Ms", playername, reasonkick) == 2))
{
    ...
}
```

Where `N` and `M` are the max widths of the `playername` and `reasonkick` buffers, respectively, eg:

```cpp
char playername[51] = {};
char reasonkick[129] = {};

if (IPlayer.IsOnline() &&
    (IPlayer.GetAdmin() >= 3) &&
    (sscanf(command, "/kick %50[^ ] %128s", playername, reasonkick) == 2))
{
    ...
}
```

The `%N[^ ]` will scan the input string until a space character is encountered or `N` characters have been scanned.  No need to specify all of the individual characters that could be encountered.  The `%Ms` will scan the rest of the input string until the end of the string is reached or until `M` characters have been scanned.  If needed, you can use `%M[^ ]` for that parameter instead.

However, in C++, this would be better handled using `std::istringstream` and `std::getline()`, instead of `sscanf()`, eg:

```cpp
if (IPlayer.IsOnline() && (IPlayer.GetAdmin() >= 3))
{
    std::istringstream iss(command);
    std::string cmd;
    if (std::getline(iss, cmd, ' ') && (cmd == "/kick"))
    {
        std::string playername, reasonkick;
        if (std::getline(iss >> std::ws, playername, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss >> std::ws, reasonkick, ' '))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to store playername and reasonkick in database, %N[^ ] will avoid SQL Injection? and what's the max size of these N and M ?

Comment: "*%N[^ ] will avoid SQL Injection?*" - no, but neither did your original code. SQL Injection has nothing to do with *which* characters are being read. Your original code allowed ASCII characters, and SQL Injection malforms SQL using ASCII chars. You are responsible for *validating* user input before using it, regardless of how you receive the input. What you should be doing instead is avoiding any possible SQL Injection attack vectors to begin with, for instance by using **parameterized SQL queries**. "*and what's the max size of these N and M ?*" - whatever you choose them to be.